# Issues with in_array

Tags: php, arrays

I have the following fairly simple code, where I need to determine if a certain value exists in an array:

```
$testvalue = $_GET['testvalue']; // 4
$list = '3, 4, 5';
$array = array($list);

if (in_array($testvalue, $array)) { // Code if found } else { // Code if not found }
```

Even though it is obvious that the number 4 is in the array, the code returns the code inside the else bracets. What have I done wrong?

Comment: probably putting the string 3,4,5 as 1 string in the array

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change the third line:

```
$array = array_map('trim', explode(',',$list));
```

Comment: Great :D Check the function pages to understand what they do too =) (http://php.net/array_map http://php.net/trim http://php.net/explode)

Answer (score 3):

`$array` here is:

```
$array = array('3, 4, 5');
```

which is not the same as:

```
$array = array(3, 4, 5);
```

So, fix the way you are creating this array.. don't do it from a string.

Comment: If I have the values in the beginning stored in a database like simply 3, 4, 5 and I then select them with $row['values'], should I do it with some other function than array(), or just have a different syntax?

Answer (score 2):

Your array contains just one value, the string `3, 4, 5`.

See the example on [CodePad](http://codepad.org/Yxy2WDs0).

If you want to convert your string in an array, you can use:

```
$array = explode(', ', $list);
```

I have added a space behind the comma, but a safer method would be to use just a comma and then trim all values.

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer, and for sharing the link. It now works like a charm!